# Выполнить событие при возвращение во фрагмент

Tags: java, android

У меня есть фрагмент, в котором вызывается второй фрагмент таким способом

```
ShareFragment frg4 = new ShareFragment ();
FragmentTransaction trans4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

trans4.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
trans4.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, frg4);
trans4.addToBackStack(null);
trans4.commit();
```

Возвращение осуществляется нажатием кнопки назад. Как при возвращении назад выполнить определенные действия? Например изменить текст в EditText?

Answer (score 0):

Можно это сделать так:
Когда мы на втором фрагменте и нажимается кнопка назад мы вместе с заменой фрагмента передаём в него аргумент.

```
ShareFragment fragment = new ShareFragment ();
Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
arguments.putString( string_key , desired_string);
fragment.setArguments(arguments);
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Потом просто проверяем наличие этого аргумента. Если он есть то мы изменяем текст в EditText а если нет то выполняем обычные действия.

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
if(arguments!=null){
EditText.setText("text");
}
```

Comment: При нажатии кнопки назад происходит переход по стеку фрагментов, никаких *" **мы** вместе с заменой фрагмента передаём .."* при этом не происходит